# Reference help about fuzzy logic and fuzzy set

Tags: reference-request, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to learn about Fuzzy alone, I was using some texts on the Internet about it, but it was very difficult to learn. I want to learn about

Fuzzy set as shaper of uncertainty.

Operations with fuzzy sets.

Characterization and properties of fuzzy sets.

The Zadeh extension principle.

Fuzzy numbers.

Fuzzy relationships.

Fuzzy relational equations.

Systems based on fuzzy rules and the Mamdani inference method.

Fuzzy controller and an application.

Compositional rule of inference.

Inference method of Takagi-Sugeno-Kang.

Approximation properties of fuzzy systems.

Measures and fuzzy integrals.

Introduction to fuzzy dynamic systems.

I found these books on web

-Fuzzy Mathematics: An Introduction for Engineers and Scientists, John N. Mordeson, Premchand S. Nair

-Fuzzy logic with engineering applications, Timothy J Ross

-Fuzzy sets and fuzzy logic, George J Klir

Does anyone know any of these books? I am totally beginner in this matter, and unfortunately none of these books has available solutions.

If anyone knows of any video material on this topic I'm grateful too.

Comment: For fuzzy set and logic, you can see : Barnabas Bede, [Mathematics of Fuzzy Sets and Fuzzy Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=LCK6BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) (2013).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I found, but this book is for beginners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience tells me if you are a beginner first start with video lectures.
Take a look here. [fuzzy](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=fuzzy%20logic&lclk=playlist&filters=playlist)
And then these are the text books which are used as references for fuzzy systems course in the university where I study.
1- [FUZZY SETS AND FUZZY LOGIC Theory and Applications](https://books.google.com/books?id=7T-GnQEACAAJ&dq=FUZZY%20SETS%20AND%20FUZZY%20LOGIC%20Theory%20and%20Applications%20GEORGE%20J.%20KLIR%20AND%20BO%20YUAN&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iNGSVYuRBsXbU_b4gIgL&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA)
2- [Advances in Fuzzy Clustering and its Applications](https://books.google.com/books?id=YjsOShrBh8AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Advances%20in%20Fuzzy%20Clustering%20and%20its%20Applications&hl=en&sa=X&ei=G9KSVeu2LMnXU5Xekng&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Advances%20in%20Fuzzy%20Clustering%20and%20its%20Applications&f=false)
3- [FUZZY MODELS AND ALGORITHMS FOR PATTERN RECOGNITION AND IMAGE PROCESSING](https://books.google.com/books?id=wIwlkgEE8_gC&printsec=frontcover&dq=FUZZY%20MODELS%20AND%20ALGORITHMS%20FOR%20PATTERN%20RECOGNITION%20AND%20IMAGE%20PROCESSING&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iNKSVZLuBYv9UJj-nng&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=FUZZY%20MODELS%20AND%20ALGORITHMS%20FOR%20PATTERN%20RECOGNITION%20AND%20IMAGE%20PROCESSING&f=false)
4- [Foundations of Fuzzy Control](https://books.google.com/books?id=HQceAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Foundations%20of%20Fuzzy%20Control%20Jan%20Jantzen&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HNOSVZf1GMfxUunfgaAB&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Foundations%20of%20Fuzzy%20Control%20Jan%20Jantzen&f=false)
5- [UNCERTAINTY AND INFORMATION Foundations of Generalized Information Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=G8ZkeSfnLGwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=UNCERTAINTY%20AND%20INFORMATION%20Foundations%20of%20Generalized%20Information%20Theory%20George%20J.%20Klir&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mdOSVeD4C4ajU8ygvdAO&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=UNCERTAINTY%20AND%20INFORMATION%20Foundations%20of%20Generalized%20Information%20Theory%20George%20J.%20Klir&f=false)
6- [FUZZY CONTROL SYSTEMS DESIGN AND ANALYSIS A Linear Matrix Inequality Approach](https://books.google.com/books?id=VH0AFTSmg5AC&printsec=frontcover&dq=FUZZY%20CONTROL%20SYSTEMS%20DESIGN%20AND%20ANALYSIS%20A%20Linear%20Matrix%20Inequality%20Approach&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OtSSVZuEHYnbU7Tng_AJ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=FUZZY%20CONTROL%20SYSTEMS%20DESIGN%20AND%20ANALYSIS%20A%20Linear%20Matrix%20Inequality%20Approach&f=false)
7- [Fuzzy Logic, Identification and Predictive Control](https://books.google.com/books?id=2bJqmlQu4VgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Fuzzy%20Logic,%20Identification%20and%20Predictive%20Control&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mdSSVfLKJcz5UrepgIgO&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Fuzzy%20Logic%2C%20Identification%20and%20Predictive%20Control&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Triangular Norms by Klement, Mesiar and Pap is a fundamental and useful book. Got it.

It is a book about t-norms, the more important operation between fuzzy set (the natural extension of the classical intersection).